# Define $a$ and $b$ rational numbers so they satisfy equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Define $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{7 + 4\sqrt{3}}} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{7 - 4\sqrt{3}}} = \sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{3}}$$
Using $\sqrt{a \pm \sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - b}}{2}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - b}}{2}}$ I got $\frac{a}{2 + \sqrt{3}} + \frac{b}{2 - \sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{3}+1$ which results in $2(a+b)+\sqrt{3}(b-a) = \sqrt{3}+1$, I'm not sure how to proceed from that.

Comment: Bring LHS to common denominator, note that the product of the roots is $\sqrt{7^2-4^2 \cdot 3} = 1$ and square both sides?

Answer (score 1):

You can move from your last equation by setting the following system of equations:
$$(b-a)\sqrt3 = \sqrt3$$ $$2(a+b) = 1$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are rational, the coefficient of $\sqrt3$ must agree on each side of the equation $2(a+b)+\sqrt{3}(b-a) = \sqrt{3}+1$ . The rational parts on each side must also agree.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{7+4\sqrt{3}}}=2-\sqrt{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{3}}}=2+\sqrt{3}$$
$$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=1+\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the completion of square as @Kay K: did.

$\sqrt{ 4 + 2 \sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{ \sqrt {3} ^ 2 + 2 \sqrt{3} + 1} = \sqrt{ (\sqrt{3} + 1)^2} = \sqrt{3} + 1$

$\sqrt{ 7 + 4 \sqrt{3}}= \sqrt{ 2^2 + 2\cdot 2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}^2} = \sqrt{ (2+ \sqrt{3})^2}= 2+ \sqrt{3}$

$\sqrt{ 7 - 4 \sqrt{3}}= \sqrt{ 2^2 - 2\cdot 2 \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}^2} = \sqrt{ (2- \sqrt{3})^2}= 2- \sqrt{3}$ since $2- \sqrt{3}>0$.

Note now that $(2+ \sqrt{3})(2- \sqrt{3} ) = 1$. Thus we need

$$a(2- \sqrt{3})+ b (2+ \sqrt{3}) = \sqrt{3} + 1$$ that is
$$2 a + 2 b = 1\\
b-a =1$$
with solution $a = -1/4, b = 3/4$